# How to change the buffer size of the Terminal in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, ide

I wanted to know how to change the buffer size of the **Terminal** in IntelliJ IDEA? Can anyone help me which properties I should change?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206381169-Terminal-Line-Buffer-increase

Answer (score 76):

You can change the terminal scrollback buffer size here:

`File » Settings » Advanced Settings » Terminal`

You have to scroll down quite a way on the Advanced Settings page to get to Terminal but you should see `Terminal scrollback buffer size:`

#### For older versions

The settings for the terminal window buffer size can be found in the IntelliJ registry.

You can find the registry through `ctrl+shift+A` and type Reg (or from the menu Help->Find Action...). You should see Registry... Click that.

Scroll down the registry and search for `terminal.buffer.max.lines.count` (you can also start typing 'term', it will take you there). It is set to 1000 lines out of the box, set it to what ever size suits you...

Comment: At least for WebStorm, there's also an option in `Preferences » General » Editor » Console`: `Override console cycle buffer size`

Comment: Thanks! ⌘+⇧+A in mac.

Comment: I cannot find this value in version 2021.2 and there appears to be no way to add a new value.

Comment: @DanSorak I've updated my answer to include how to change it via settings in later versions of intellij

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score 14):

As of IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2, this setting has been reintroduced. From [the link provided in Günter Zöchbauer's comment](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206381169-Terminal-Line-Buffer-increase):

This setting is now under Settings - Advanced Settings: Terminal > Terminal scrollback buffer size
[image: Image of the Terminal scrollback buffer size setting]

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately not for the terminal, but for the console in Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2019.1:

- open `"File" => "Settings..." => "Editor" => "General" => "Console"`
- activate `"Override console cycle buffer size"` from its default
  value of 1024kB to your needs.
- restart the IDE

Comment: Doesn't apply to the terminal, but to the output of run-console.

Comment: @HugoPassos you are right, does not affect Terminal

Answer (score 5):

Add this line into idea.properties

```
terminal.buffer.max.lines.count = 20000
```

Terminal and console are different, the console configs do not effect terminal.